# minecraft button 1 takes me to menu every time

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Every time I hold button 1 to break a block it sends me to the menu screen.  I can't figure it out so its impossible to play classic.  I've tried re installing Java 7 but that didn't change a thing, and changing game quality didn't do anything either.  I want to play minecraft but can't unless this is fixed.