# Trying to break blocks opens Inventory instead

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In every mode of Minecraft it will not let us break anything. When I click on a block to break it, the game goes to the inventory screen, and the block does not break. How do we fix it?

Comment: Try re-binding left mouse button to "Attack" from "Open inventory". Also, you can not break items in Minecraft, only pick them up. It is blocks what breaks.

Comment: What do you mean 'goes into the inventory and does not break'? Surely if it's gone into your inventory it's been broken?

Comment: @fredley I bet it's "*game* goes into the inventory and *block* does not break".

Comment: possible duplicate of [minecraft button 1 takes me to menu every time](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119533/minecraft-button-1-takes-me-to-menu-every-time)

Comment: @MBraedly That question was abandoned by the OP and closed as it lacked necessary details to diagnose the problem. *This* is a nice, clear question. If anything, that other should be flagged as a duplicate of this one so that we keep the clearest Q&A as the main one.

Answer (score 8):

1. Hit <kbd>esc</kbd> to go to the options menu
2. Click `Controls`
3. Set the key for 'Button 1' to left click, and set the key for 'Inventory' to <kbd>e</kbd>.

It's highly recommended to stick to the [defaults](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Controls).